# Error with rollback transaction inside an IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, transactions

Why when I have a procedure in sql server like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc
    @x      INT
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION my_proc
    BEGIN TRY
        IF (@x < 0)
        BEGIN
           ROLLBACK TRANSACTION my_proc
        END

        UPDATE test SET x = @x
        COMMIT TRANSACTION my_proc
    END
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION my_proc
    END CATCH
GO
```

and I execute another procedure that calls this one passing the parameter...

```
exec secondProc 10
```

even if the value is greater then 0 I get this error?

> Cannot  rollback my_proc, no transaction or savepoint of that name was
>   found. 
>   Transaction count after EXECUTE indicate a mismatching number of
>   BEGIN and COMMIT statements

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You have an outer procedure that calls this one? Do you have transactions in the other one too? Nested transactions are a myth, they do not work as you think they should. Also, if you pass in a value < 0 this will fail because it will rollback and then try to commit your transaction.

Comment: looks like you started the transaction in the secondProc too, also There is nothing to rollback if @x < 0, you also need END TRY

Comment: The procedure that calls this one also have a transaction.. by the way all my procedures have begin transaction  inside them.
It would be better if iput this "if" statement outside the transaction with a "return" instead of rollback?

Comment: If you have begin transaction in every procedure you are asking for trouble. You simply cannot nest transactions. It doesn't matter where you try to control them from, if you have nested transactions your code will fail. Each time you start a new transaction all it does is increment TRANCOUNT. As soon as you hit a single commit or rollback, TRANCOUNT will be 0.

Comment: You can google sql nested transactions and find plenty of references to the myth of nested transactions. Here is one...http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Comment: But why this code got a mismatching with this counts if my example didnt hit the IF statement? The first procedure opens the transaction (count = 1), the second procedure opens another transaction (count 2), x got updated, second procedures commit its transaction (count 1) and first procedure commit its transaction (count 0)

Comment: Because you nested procedures. Your outer proc has a transaction and in your inner proc you either commit or rollback the transaction. That means that when you get back to the first proc the trancount has changed. It has nothing to do with the IF statement, it has to do with how transactions work in sql server.